# How to show thumbnails of the running video as tooltip when user puts the mouse on seekbar in jw player?

Tags: video-streaming, thumbnails, jwplayer

I have a video and I want to show thumbnail of the video as user puts in the mouse on the seek bar of that particular time as tool tip.

I am using jw player.

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do it, and if not is there any documentation about this kind of feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not there in the jwplayer right now, but it is there in youtube api, you can use it.